# how to install pytorch version 0.1.12 in anaconda 3.6 windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

Tried to install with this command but still didn't work-> conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch=0.1.12

Also tried installing using this command:
conda install pytorch=0.1.12 -c pytorch
How can it be installed with python anaconda 3.6?

Comment: Can you show us the error message ??

Comment: Solving environment: failed
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - pytorch=0.1.12
Current channels:

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that `Python 3.5 or later` is installed as well.

- *Go* to [this link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-X0-FlSGfCYdTNldW02UGl4MXM) and *download* "pytorch-0.1.12-py36_0.1.12cu80.tar.bz2".
- Now *navigate* to the ***downloaded file*** and *install* it through `Anaconda console` `conda install [path to file]/pytorch-0.1.12-py36_0.1.12cu80.tar.bz2`

***Note:***
*If it requires some additional modules, use conda or pip to install those addition modules via:*

```
conda install (module)
```

or

```
pip install (module)
```

Comment: i need the one without cuda

Comment: See this https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pytorch-gpu/0.1.12/download/linux-64/pytorch-gpu-0.1.12-py36_nomkl_0.tar.bz2